# recursion in counting the ocurrences of a number

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have found a problem that it says it should be solved by using recursion. The question is that given a certain number it should count the number of 8s that are present in it, but if two 8s are one next to another it should be counted as double. For example:

```
  48 should return 1
  4881 should return 4
  8818 should return 5
```

I have made the following program in Scheme:

```
(define (count n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0
      (begin
        (if (= (remainder n 100) 88)
            2
            (begin
              (if (= (remainder n 10) 8) 
                   1
                   0))
            )
        (+ (count (quotient n 10))))))
```

The problem is that everytime I run it returns 0, what am I missing? I do not want to use lists or set! for using an auxiliar variable. Any help?

Comment: I don't think you need the `begin`s..

Comment: .. but you will need to recurse on intermediate answers (and somewhere you might want to define quotient..?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep iterating whenever you find a match, and the sums don't seem right. Also, instead of nesting `if`s it's better to use `cond`, like this:

```
(define (count n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= (remainder n 100) 88)
         (+ 4 (count (quotient n 100))))
        ((= (remainder n 10) 8)
         (+ 1 (count (quotient n 10))))
        (else
         (+ (count (quotient n 10))))))
```

It works with your examples:

```
(count 48)
=> 1
(count 4881)
=> 4
(count 8818)
=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to count scans of 8s in a helper and keep a current number of hits and a total tally for previous scans.

```
(define (funny-eights n)
  (define (aux n cur total)
    (cond ((= (remainder n 10) 8)
           (aux (quotient n 10) (+ cur 1) total))
          ((> cur 1)
           (aux (quotient n 10) 0 (+ total (* 2 cur))))
          ((= cur 1)
           (aux (quotient n 10) 0 (+ total cur)))
          ((> n 0)
           (aux (quotient n 10) 0 total))
          (else
           total)))
  (aux n 0 0))

(funny-eights 488838288) ; ==> 11  or 3*2 + 1 + 2*2
```